# C++ program need lines words and characters count

Tags: c++

I have an assignment where i need to count lines, words and characters from a file. I'm having a problem counting the right amount of characters and words since if it gets doubled space it counts like a character and a word.

the output should be

Example

```
lines  words  characters  filename

 3     5        29        testfile
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
string lines, words, chars, file1, file2;

ifstream infile;
ofstream outfile;
char c;

int countLines = 0;
int countChars = 0;
int countWords = 0;
cout<< "Enter the file name" << endl;
cin >> file1;
infile.open(file1.c_str());


while(!infile.eof())
{
    if(infile.peek() == 1)
        break;
    c = infile.get();
    if(c != '\n')
       countChars++;
    else
        countLines++;

    if(c == ' '|| c =='\n')
        countWords++;

}

  //  countChars = countChars - countWords;



cout << setw(12) << countLines << setw(12) << countWords << setw(12) << countChars  << endl;

infile.close();



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code, with a debugger, while watching the values of the variables, so you could find out, where your code does something that you didn't expect?

Comment: You ought to think through the definition of a word a little better.  As you discovered, you are just counting spaces, not words.  You'll probably need to use more than the current character to decide if you have just completed a word.

Comment: You'll also probably want to consider what happens at the end of the file. If there is no space after a word, does it count as a word?  It probably does.

Answer (score 1):

I believe OP's purpose to ask this question is to find out why his/her code is not working, therefore I will **answer in this perspective**.

> counting the right amount of  words

1. C++ define EOF(end of file) as -1, so include a check for EOF too, or you will miss a word count.

> if it gets doubled space it counts like a character and a word.

2. You can use a boolean test to solve this, if you encountered a space, turn on the boolean, and skip if next char is a space, too.
3. I suppose your character count doesn't count in punctuation? so check for `c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'`. If your assignment count punctuation as character count too, ignore this point.

Below is a correct version code that is modified based on your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string lines, words, chars, file1, file2;

    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    char c;
    bool findNextString = false;

    int countLines = 0;
    int countChars = 0;
    int countWords = 0;
    cout << "Enter the file name" << endl;
    cin >> file1;
    infile.open(file1.c_str());


    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        if (infile.peek() == 1)
            break;
        c = infile.get();

        // use the boolean to find next valid string
        if (findNextString && c == ' ')
            continue;
        else
            findNextString = false;

        // there is a structure issue with your code.
        // you should think of the priority of checking

        // do not check by rejection, because you will count in punctuation too.
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        {
            countChars++;
        }
        else if (c == '\n')
        {
            countLines++;
            countWords++; // <- add word too
        }
        else if (c == ' ' || c == EOF)
        {
            countWords++;
            findNextString = true;
        }
    }

    cout << setw(12) << countLines << setw(12) << countWords << setw(12) << countChars << endl;

    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regarding `while (!infile.eof())` Sure, OP did it, but it's a mistake we should avoid propagating. At the very least you should flag it to them as a significant logic problem, and if you're going to leave it you can't truthfully call this corrected code.

Answer (score 1):

Use getline for reading file line by line

```
while(getline(file,str))
{
    countLines++;
    countChars += str.length();
    countWords += CountWords(str);
 }
```

Which file is an iofstream object and str is a string. And for counting number of words(**CountWords**), you have [several ways](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/30929/). One of them is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>

int countWords(std::string str) {
  vector< std::string > result;
  boost::algorithm::split_regex(result, str, regex( "\\s+" ));
  return result.size();
}
```